# Is "manually talented" a thing, linguistically-speaking?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

Came across "[these people are] manually talented" in an English language test.The context was a group of people who were good at karate or ballgames, but also origami, pottery, sculpting, etc.

To me, it sounds more than stilted, and feels like it was taken directly from Polish (though the Polish phrase would only really apply to the non-sporty skills, not eg. karate). I would personally say "good with their hands", "crafty", or something along those lines.

But am I wrong? Does "manually talented" actually exist in English? (There are 451 results for it on Google, but that seems like a very small number for a concept that I would imagine is fairly commonplace...)

Comment: Usually people would say *"physically talented"* in the cases that you listed. *"Manually talented"* implies a talent specifically related to the use of one's *hands*. Karate and baseball use your hands, I guess, but the hands are not the only important part of the body that is used in these activities.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oooh, good point, re karate using body parts other than hands. Hadn't thought of that.

Ok, but would "physically talented" encompass origami and pottery? And, if we were to forget sports altogether and focus only on crafts etc, would "manually talented" sound ok then?

Comment: Dextrous/deft:  skillful in physical movements; especially of the hands; "a deft waiter"; "deft fingers massaged her face"; "dexterous of hand and inventive of mind"

Comment: You could apply *physically talented* to origami or pottery, but usually people would say *artistically talented* —even moreso than they would say *manually talented*. Most people would view the largest barrier to entry in the arts the creativity that is required and not the dexterity that is applied during creation.

Comment: Sounds like someone's translation of the idiom "good with his hands."

Comment: @Robusto And that covers a multitude of sins!

Comment: @Robusto That's what I'm leaning towards as well. But since I live in Poland, I sometimes wonder if my native speaker sense of English has gotten muddled or something.

Comment: @Josh61 "Deft fingers/hands" totally encapsulates the idea behind the Polish equivalent (and ooh, I like your last example!), and so I'm assuming it's what the author wanted (and somewhat failed) to say.

Comment: While "good with his hands" is probably the most common, the phrase "*manually adept*" does have some frequency: https://www.google.com.my/search?q=%22manually+adept%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=iXj_VNXEIsuxggSThYDgDg

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically, there's nothing wrong with it, but "manually" means by hand, or with no machine or computer. People can be physically or kinesthetically talented or gifted, even unusually proprioceptively adept. But "manually talented" is meaningless, even given this context.

Comment: But (devil's advocate here, keep in mind I dislike the phrase)... wouldn't it theoretically make sense to say someone is e.g. manually talented at sewing (but rubbish at using a sewing machine)? And then, couldn't a pianist be considered "manually talented" (while not necessarily physically talented overall)?

Comment: @AlicjaZ You make a good point, but I still think the phrase is stilted beyond normalcy.

Comment: I imagine a pianist would like to be considered _musically_ talented. "Manually talented" requires such specificity of context and subsequent linguistic gymnastics that I vote to ditch it. Despite its technical correctness.

Comment: I agree. When a term needs multiple caveats, contextual information and special pleading to be acceptable in the situations in which it is being used, there seems little point in using it — especially when there are so many other, more suitable terms to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Sure..

> [MANUAL][1]
>
> adjective
>
> 1. done, operated, worked, etc., by the hand or hands rather than by an electrical or electronic device: a manual gearshift.
> 2. involving or using human effort, skill, power, energy, etc.; physical: manual labor.
> 3. of or relating to the hand or hands: manual deformities.
>
>    [1]: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manually

Manual isn't confined to just the hands.  Manual labor would mean physical labor just as manual skills could mean physical skills.

Comment: Whether or not it's confined to just the hands is one thing... Another is whether the phrase itself is proper English, though.

Comment: I think the term "by hand" in the definition of manual is what is confusing about the word meaning. "By hand" can mean doing it yourself without assistance.  Although I think there are more proper ways to say manually talented, by definition, I believe that it is proper English.

Comment: I think that I've said all of this above? But thank-you @SUM GUY for the dictionary post.

Comment: You are welcome.  I didn't copy and paste that url either.  I typed it in manually using my toes.  I'm manually talented like that.  ;)